# can event.isTrusted be trusted?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, captcha

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

I am wondering why we have these obnoxious captcha solutions, when we could just test for this event property. Can this be trusted or is it possible to emulate it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you will find out with [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) is that the event was not called by the `dispatchEvent()` function and was not programmatically modified.

Today's captcha soltuions use much more advanced techniques such as **behavioral analysis**. Bots don't have to run just as a script. They can very reliably simulate real users. Not all of the captcha solutions are obnoxious. Some of them run without user interuption just with veryfing IP reputation and device fingerprinting. For example [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) will never interrupt your users.

Answer (score 1):

I've just asked this question on HackerNews. Appearently, someone can roll their own browser, and possibly set `isTrusted` to `true` (or might not, I don't know yet).